# global $post; in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, metabox

Is there a reason when using the `add_meta_box()` callback, that when I do `global $post` I can't seem to access anything, or get the ID. I'm in WooCommerce, do I need to use `global $product` instead... if so why?

When I do `add_meta_box( 'supplier_package_box', __( 'Supplier', 'supplier' ), 'populate_meta_box' );`

In my callback:

```
function populate_meta_box(){
    global $post
    print_r($post);
    echo '</br>';
```

`$post` is always empty... for context I want to check if a post meta exists so I can populate an input box if necessary. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid using global variables where possible. For metaboxes you should use the `$post` variable that is passed to the callback function instead:

```
add_meta_box( 'supplier_package_box', __( 'Supplier', 'supplier' ), 'populate_meta_box' );

function populate_meta_box( $post ){
    print_r($post);
}
```